# jQuery iterate through array on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have tried to look everywhere for a solution but I can't seem to understand how this can be properly done. Essentially I have an XML that I want to pull data from. I want the page to load the first entry, once the user clicks the forward button I want it to iterate through the XML until it reaches the end. The same would go for the back button.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var name = [];
        var description = [];
        var html_screenshot_01 = [];
        var html_screenshot_02 = [];
        var site_link = [];
        var source_link = [];
        var demo_link = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "projects_html.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('name').each(function(){ name.push($(this).text()); });
                $(xml).find('description').each(function(){ description.push($(this).text()); });
                $(xml).find('html_screenshot_01').each(function(){ html_screenshot_01.push($(this).text()); });
                $(xml).find('html_screenshot_02').each(function(){ html_screenshot_02.push($(this).text()); });
                $(xml).find('site_link').each(function(){ site_link.push($(this).text()); });
                $(xml).find('source_link').each(function(){ source_link.push($(this).text()); });
                $(xml).find('demo_link').each(function(){ demo_link.push($(this).text()); });                   

                $(xml).find('projects').each(function(){


                    $('#name').empty().append(name[0]);
                    $('#description').empty().append(description);
                    $("img#html_screenshot_01").attr("src", html_screenshot_01);
                    $("img#html_screenshot_02").attr("src", html_screenshot_02);
                    $("a#site_link").attr("src", site_link);
                    $("a#source_link").attr("src", source_link);
                    $("a#demo_link").attr("src", demo_link);    

                    $('a#site_link').filter(function() {return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''}).css("visibility", "hidden")
                    $('a#source_link').filter(function() {return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''}).css("visibility", "hidden")                    
                    $('a#demo_link').filter(function() {return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''}).css("visibility", "hidden")
                });
            }
        });
        $("#next").click(function() {
            var i = 0;
            i++;
            $('#name').empty().append(name[i]);
            return false;
        });
        $("#back").click(function() {
            alert('back');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I understand I have: $('#name').empty().append(name[0]);

This was for testing purposes so I could have the first entry load, while I looked at the button functionality.

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over an array? You have for loops, while loops, do-while loops, jquerie's .each() function...

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, essentially yes I need to know how to iterate through the array. I've tried various for loops and the jQuery .each function, however each implementation either;

a. loads the page without any XML data, and will refresh the page each time the next button is clicked
b. loads the page with the initial XML entry and then refreshes the page when the button is clicked (doesn't increment essentially)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move you   `var i = 0;` out of the next click event

```
.
.

var i = 0;
$("#next").click(function() {
.
.
.
```

Comment: I love how I could develop 48 lines of functional code and somehow not comprehend where my iterator should be placed, thank you for saving me the next 10 hours of my life. 
http://www.roflcorner.com/wp-content/gallery/facepalm/mCU8jmcCknhaneztKwDmYdCyo1_500.jpg

Comment: @AdrianVona, if this solution works for you then **Accept the Answer** and **Upvote** too if useful.